# how to add custom container inside product.info.main container in magento 2.3.1

Tags: xml, catalog, magento2.3.1, catalog-prodct-view.xml

how to add custom container in class="product-info-main" referenceContainer="content" and  inside catalog.product.view.xml file

> catalog.product.view.xml

```
  <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="product.info.parts" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-parts" before=""/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

but it's not working

Comment: did you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Need some correction in your code:

- Add `-` in before element i.e before="-"
- Empty container will not render, You need to add some block Or can move existing element in it.
- If need empty container, You can add empty block to force container rendering. Please refer  [Link](https://gist.github.com/vasilii-b/1947fd38c9b8822ff82e2d85d9e83723)

Hope above will help!

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This way**

```
<container name="product.info.parts" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-parts" before="-">
    <!-- Add block - 1 -->
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string">BlockName</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <!-- Add block - 2 -->
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
           name="product.info.addtocart"
           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
</container>
 OR
<container name="product.info.parts" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-parts" before="-"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add the Below code in your **catalog_product_view.xml** file.

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <container name="product.info.parts" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-parts" before="-"/>
 </referenceContainer>
```